# To create OAuth signature for multi dimensional array

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth, google-oauth

How to create OAuth signature string for multi-dimensional array

**Example:**

```
<?php


 //MULTI ARRAY
    $a = array(

        //KEY 1 CONTAINS AN ARRAY
        1=>array('name'=>sundar','email'=>'s7sunder@gmail.com'),

        //KEY 2 CONTAINS AN ARRAY
        2=>array('name'=>sundar1','email'=>'s7sunder1@gmail.com')
    );
?>
```

how to form signature string like this for OAuth

Signature String:

```
status=Hello%20Ladies%20%2b%20Gentlemen%2c%20a%20signed%20OAuth%20request%21
```